# Symfony 3 get current user inside entity

Tags: orm, symfony, fosuserbundle

I was wondering if there is a way that i can initialize the property owner with an entity User of FOSUserBundle so that it contains the user who created the Post

I want to do this inside the constructor as shown below.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
  /* here are defined some attributs */
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $owner;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->owner = /* get current user */ ;
  }

}
```

Is there a way to do this by replacing the comment in the constructor with something ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Doctrine does not actually use the constructor so no.  Why not just set a relation between Post and User?

Comment: relation is already there, when a new Post is created the owner attributes is initialized with the currently connected User

Comment: So all you want is to initialize the owner when a new posted is first created?  If so, both of the answers below are valid.  Personally I would go with the factory approach possibly adding the create method to the post repository instead of a standalone class.  But all the approaches listed make sense.

Comment: don't know why someone downvoted a legitimate question... having said that, this question sounds like developer laziness.

Comment: @DonOmondi - Exactly.  Being lazy is a key component being an excellent developer.  Only an idiot wants to work harder than they have to.

Comment: i'm in fact lazy, i want the code to be simple and easy to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are way over-complicating this issue. When you create a new Post in your controller, either in the controller or in the repository do something like this:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Post; //at top of controller

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$post = new Post();
$em->persist( $post );
$post->setOwner( $user );
// set other fields in your post entity
$em->flush();
```

Comment: In Symfony 4, in a Controller context you can do ```$this->getUser()```

Comment: @skirato OP question is about Entity context, where you cannot do that

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't. [*]

There are at least two ways to deal with this:

- Create your Post entities through a factory service which populates the
  `owner` property:

  ```
  namespace My\Bundle\EntityFactory;

  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
  use My\Bundle\Entity\Post;

  class PostFactory
  {
      private $tokenStorage;

      public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
      {
          $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
      }

      public function createPost()
      {
          $user = $this->tokenStorage()->getToken()->getUser();
          $post = new Post($user);
      }
  }
  ```

  <sub>(for this example, you will have to modify your `Post` constructor to
  accept the owner as a parameter)</sub>

  In services.yml:

  ```
  services:
      post_factory:
          class: My\Bundle\EntityFactory\PostFactory
          arguments: [@security.token_storage]
  ```

  To create an entity from your controller:

  ```
  $post = $this->container->get('post_factory')->createPost();
  ```
- If you can tolerate that the owner will only be set once you persist the
  entity, you can use a doctrine event listener:

  ```
  namespace My\Bundle\EventListener;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
  use My\Bundle\Entity\Post;

  class PostOwnerAssignmentListener
  {
      private $tokenStorage;

      public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
      {
          $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
      }

      public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
      {
          $entity = $event->getEntity();
          if ($entity instanceof Post && !$entity->getOwner()) {
              $entity->setOwner($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  In services.yml:

  ```
  services:
      post_owner_assignment_listener:
          class: My\Bundle\EventListener\PostOwnerAssignmentListener
          arguments: [@security.token_storage]
          tags:
              - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersit }
  ```

  The advantage here is that the owner gets assigned no matter how and where
  the `Post` is created.

<sub>[*]: Well, technically with the default `app.php` you could access the
kernel by declaring `global $kernel;` in your constructor and go from there,
however this is *very* strongly discouraged and may break in strange and subtle
ways.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**For Symfony 4+** with Autowiring and Entity event listener:

In */EventListener/PostPrePersistListener.php:*

```php
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class PostPrePersistListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(Post $post, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $post->setOwner($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
    }
}
```

In *services.yaml:*

```yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\PostPrePersistListener:
        autowire: true 
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: 'App\Entity\Post', event: prePersist }
```

Modifying *services.yaml* is required as Symfony cannot know that this custom service is tagged to hook on `doctrine.event_listener`

This works at Entity-level as asked, to ensure Controller do not handle the *owner* value.

Comment: I had to change doctrine.orm.event_listener to doctrine.event_listener.

Comment: @quartarian Be careful, if you use `doctrine.event_listener` you cannot specify the _'entity'_ field in the YAML file. So it will be called for all entities. This is fine if you want to do your stuff for any entity, or if you filter out entities with `$event->getObject() instanceof YourEntityClass`

Comment: @ErdalG. In here, the event listener name should be **doctrine.orm.entity_listener** (not the **doctrine.orm.event_listener**)

Comment: @Kusala good catch, thx!